# Convert eloquent relationship into vue js code

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, vue.js, vue-resource

I have this project that should fetch values from a pivot table and one to many relationship. When using the eloquent syntax I am getting the correct output as seen here:

ReservationController

```
public function index()
{
    $secSubs = Student::find(1);

    return $secSubs->sectionSubjects;

}
```

form.blade.php

```
@inject('reservation', 'App\Http\Controllers\ReservationController')
@foreach( $reservation->index() as $reserved )
<tr>
  <td>{{ $reserved->section->section_code }}</td>
  <td>{{ $reserved->subject->subject_code }}</td>
  <td>{{ $reserved->subject->subject_description }}</td>
  <td>{{ $reserved->schedule }}</td>
  <td>{{ $reserved->subject->units }}</td>
  <td>{{ $reserved->room_no }}</td>
  <td>
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

However I want to make use of the feature of vue js so that my page will automatically be populated with value being fetch as seen below.

```
new Vue({
el: '#app-layout',

data: {

    subjects: []

},
ready: function(){
    this.fetchSubjects();
},
methods:{

    fetchSubjects: function(){
        var self = this;

        this.$http({
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/reservation',
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function (subjects){
            self.subjects = subjects.data;
            console.log('success');
        }, function (response){
            console.log('failed');
        });
    },

}
});
```

form.blade.php

```
<tr v-for="subject in subjects">
  <td>@{{ subject.section.section_code }}</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>@{{ subject.room_no }}</td>
  <td>
     <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

As seen in my form.blade.php I cannot get the value of section_code. Am I missing something here?

UPDATE:
SectionSubject Model

```
class SectionSubject extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'section_subject';

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class, 'section_subject_student','section_subject_id','student_id'
            )->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function assignStudents(Student $student)
    {
        return $this->students()->save($student);
    }

    public function subject()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class);
    }

    public function section()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Section::class);
    }

}
```

Student Model

```
public function sectionSubjects()
     {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SectionSubject::class,'section_subject_student', 'student_id','section_subject_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
     }
```

Section Model

```
class Section extends Model
{
    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class)->withPivot('id','schedule','room_no');
    }

    public function sectionSubjects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SectionSubject::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see 'data' array anywhere, your controller returns subjects directly. Therefore, can you try to replace self.subjects = subjects.data; with self.$set('subjects', subjects); instead? Also, it looks like you are expecting an array of subjects in the front-end, but you are passing a single subject in the controller?

Comment: @Denis Mysenko thanks for your reply. I did change the self.subjects = subjects.data; with self.$set('subjects', subjects); but still not getting the subject_code value. In the controller I am returning a the relationship of Student and SectionSubect Model which is the sectionSubjects. Then what I did is to fetch the relationship model of SectionSubject model and Section Model. That is why in my form.blade.php i call reserved->section->section_code. I' ll update my code above.

Comment: since you are expecting an array, but returning a single item, you can also try self.subjects.push(subjects);

Comment: @Denis Mysenko Tried your solution but Im getting this error in console Error when evaluating expression "subject.section.section_code": TypeError: Cannot read property 'section_code' of undefined. Also this when using the push :all-3f2b98c050.js:23790 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: self.subjects.push is not a function(…)

Comment: @Denis Mysenko kindly see my updated code above thanks.

Comment: @DenisMysenko kindly view updated code

Answer (score 3):

it is not problem of laravel or vuejs.

this code.

```
    this.$http({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/reservation',
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function (subjects){
        self.subjects = subjects.data;
        console.log('success');
    }, function (response){
        console.log('failed');
    });
```

you can see this ajax request will get answer in json.

and json is pretty much static content. as "Eloquent" within php scope its an object so if you ask relational data from it, it will execute call and return its relational data but json can not do that.

so to make it work you need to convert whole relational data and create one massive array which holds all relational data then encode it.

for example :

```
$user = App\User::with('roles')->first();
return $user->toJson();
```

now if you return this it will contain "user.roles.name" this value as we eagerly loaded that and converted to json.

in you case :

```
$subjects = App\Reservation::with('section')->all(); 
return $subjects->toJson();
```

now you can use subjects and loop it "subject.section.section_code" as section is eagerly loaded and added to array and converted to json.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you @hardik-satasiya 
my list.vue product eg:
<td>{{ product.category.name }}</td>